# Unable to clone gitlab repo behind proxy using ssh

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab

I am having some trouble while cloning the gitlab repo on corporate network when using the url 
**git clone git@gitlab.com:TestProject/Test.git**
whereas cloning using https just works fine.

Below error is seen while cloning

ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists

Comment: What kind of proxy is this?

Comment: @Kenster: basically i am trying to access above url from corporate network.

Comment: If the proxy blocks port 22 to external servers, you're probably out of luck.  Why can't you just use https checkouts?

Comment: @StephenNewell i have deployed android source by creating multiple repos in gitlab ,and for accessing that i am using repo sync, which prompt multiple times authentication(gitlab username & password ). So to avoid this i was looking for cloning using ssh instead of https in my manifest file

Answer (score 1):

So it seemed like the port 22 was blocked by the corporate firewall due to which git clone was failing.

Although the other problem i was facing of multiple authentication ( gitlab username & password ) prompt during repo sync got resolved by using

```
git config --global credential.helper store --file ~/.my-credentials
```

where ~/.my-credentials contains the gitlab url with username & password